# How can we count the PK and repeat this count for the entire list of PK?

Tags: plsql, oracle11g, rownum

How can we count the PK and repeat this count for the entire list of PK?

For example:

**Table A** (that contains 3000 registers, for example)

```
ID
0001
0002
0003
0004
0005
...
```

Using without any filter, we expect:

```
COUNT(*) | ID
3000     | 0001
3000     | 0002
3000     | 0003
3000     | 0004
3000     | 0005
...
```

Bt when using filters to restric the results, the COUNT must reflect according the result in screen for example:

```
select ...
where ID IN (0001,0002,0003,0004,0005)
```

Then should be:

```
COUNT(*) | ID
5        | 0001
5        | 0002
5        | 0003
5        | 0004
5        | 0005
```

This appears to be very simple, but I'm not able to do this.

I've tried to use `rownum`, `count(PK)`, `max(rownum)` and haven't success.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This?

```
SQL> select count(*) from emp;

  COUNT(*)
----------
        12

SQL> select empno, count(*) over (order by null) cnt from emp;

     EMPNO        CNT
---------- ----------
      7369         12
      7499         12
      7521         12
      7566         12
      7654         12
      7698         12
      7782         12
      7839         12
      7844         12
      7900         12
      7902         12
      7934         12

12 rows selected.

SQL> select empno, count(*) over (order by null) cnt from emp where deptno = 10;

     EMPNO        CNT
---------- ----------
      7782          3
      7839          3
      7934          3

SQL>
```

Comment: Litthefoot, that is it!!! Thank you! I could never imagine something like `COUNT(*) OVER (ORDER BY NULL)`.